# Возможно ли получить UID / хэш от Android Fingerprint API?

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Здравствуйте.

Можно ли в Java получить уникальный идентификатор, или хэш (короче грубо говоря последовательность байтов) от пальца при работе с Android Fingerprint API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не совсем согласен с предыдущим ответом, так как можно сказать, что у отпечатка пальцев в системе есть ID. Например, если вывести содержимое файла `/data/system/users/0/settings_fingerprint.xml`, то можно увидеть следующее:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<fingerprints>
  <fingerprint fingerId="1" name="Lex 1" groupId="0" deviceId="0" />
  <fingerprint fingerId="2" name="Lex 2" groupId="0" deviceId="0" />
  <fingerprint fingerId="3" name="Lex 3" groupId="0" deviceId="0" />
  <fingerprint fingerId="4" name="Lex 4" groupId="0" deviceId="0" />
</fingerprints>
```

А если взглянуть на исходники `fingerprintd`, то можно увидеть в методе `void FingerprintDaemonProxy::hal_notify_callback(const fingerprint_msg_t *msg)` такой фрагмент кода.

```
case FINGERPRINT_AUTHENTICATED:
            ALOGD("onAuthenticated(fid=%d, gid=%d)",
                    msg->data.authenticated.finger.fid,
                    msg->data.authenticated.finger.gid);
            if (msg->data.authenticated.finger.fid != 0) {
                const uint8_t* hat = reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t *>(&msg->data.authenticated.hat);
                instance->notifyKeystore(hat, sizeof(msg->data.authenticated.hat));
            }
            callback->onAuthenticated(device,
                    msg->data.authenticated.finger.fid,
                    msg->data.authenticated.finger.gid);
            break;
```

## UPD#1

Для желающих более подробно разобраться с механизмом работы `fingerprint` в ***Android*** рекомендую прочитать [эту работу](http://www.delaat.net/rp/2015-2016/p30/report.pdf).

Comment: То-есть, можно попробовать "дёрнуть" палец из keystore ?!

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy можете проверить на рутованом телефоне после установки fingerprint защиты, появляется файл `/data/system/users/0/fpdata/user.db' но он пошифрован и я не добрался пока еще до ключа. А вообще есть два метода подменить fingerprintd или перехватывать его Binder IPC. Более подробно можете почитать в [этой работе](http://www.delaat.net/rp/2015-2016/p30/report.pdf)

Comment: Приложите ссылку работы в ответ пж, там просто много по теме нужного :)

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy у вас интересные вопросы и ответы =) добавил ссылку. как бы с вами сконтачиться, может у нас будут общие интересы в ИБ и исследованиях...

Comment: Как id пальца в системе связан с уникальным идентификатором пальца, о котором спрашивает ТС?

Comment: @eugeneek просто ТС не особо четко знал чего хочет, посмотрев на его вопросы, мне показалось, что направление вопроса было немного другим, нежели то, на которое ответили вы

Comment: @LexHobbit здравствуйте, если что пишите на почту, она у меня в профиле :)

Answer (score 3):

Fingerprint Api в Android не отдаёт никаких данных о снятом отпечатке. Вся работа с ним происходит исключительно внутри SDK.

К тому же, такого понятия, как хеш (уид) для отпечатка пальца не существует. При снятии отпечатка, он переводится в набор характерных признаков, называемых минуши (количество, характер линий, координаты, углы излома). При следующем сканировании набор этих признаков будет другим, так как мы можем сдвинуть палец, приложить его под другим углом и т.д. При сравнении наборов, ищутся соответствия признаков и если их количество превышает определённый порог, то считается, что отпечатки идентичны.

Таким образом, даже если преобразовать исходный отпечаток в некий УИД, он будет бесполезен, потому что практически никогда не будет совпадать с полученным УИД при повторном сканировании.

Answer (score 1):

Когда вы добавляете в настройках безопасности системы новый отпечаток пальца, создаётся fingerprint key и сохраняется в хранилище. Запись в хранилище, кроме самого ключа, имеет ещё числовой идентификтор, назначаемый по порядку, и необязательное имя. Всё, что можно сделать из приложения - это запросить у системной службы Fingerprint Service есть ли в хранилище такой отпечаток, какой сейчас прижат к сканеру. Нельзя даже определить, какой из ключей хранилища соответствует прижатому в данный момент пальцу. И даже если вы сможете как-то извлечь из хранилища fingerprint key, толку вам от него немного, он пригоден только для проверки данных получаемых от сканера и только на этом же устройстве.